# Please set the code language for the [reactjs] tag to lang-js

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Because I'm seriously tired of having to edit every second [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) question, just to add the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, just to get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 6):

I've set the default language to JS for [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)... let's see how that goes.